# Allot customer group according to their email id

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

In a magento project I need to allot customer group to customer according to their email id.
Like I have customer group in admin "xxx" and "yyy"
NOw I want at time of signup if user have id abc@xxx.com, group named xxx allot to him or if he has abc@yyy.in, group "yyy" allot to him.

Please suggest me ..how can I accomplish this task or please refer any document.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely way to succeed is to override `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` and provide your own `getGroupId()` method. This method should check the domain of the email address (`$this->getEmail()`) and then both set and return the ID of the group. If it doesn't recognise the domain then pass it back to the parent to be processed as normal.